# Choose properties to be COLLECTed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I choose which properties to be collected in a Cypher [COLLECT](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-collect) statement?

I can do `COLLECT([profile.name, profile.email])` but then I don't get the properties names.

Say I have ProfileA which is connected to several ProfileB's, I'd like to have returned ProfileA and a collection of ProfileB's where `ProfileA-->ProfileB`, but only ProfileB.name and ProfileB.email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there's no support for literal maps in collections, so we can't build a collection of maps, which it sounds like you want to be able to do.

Your idea of passing a collection to collect should work, and you'll get a collection of collections where the name is always first and the email is always last.

Another option is to do `collect(profile.name) as names, collect(profile.email) as emails` and have two collections.

Or, you could just have the full nodes. Sorry that there's not a better way (AFAIK)!